# Blogger - Changing style for comment textarea

Tags: css, html, iframe, comments, blogger

I most likely know the answer but maybe I'm wrong so lets try.

I want to change the appearance of the comment form from Blogger (blogspot - Google blog system). Sadly, this awful little form is embedded in an iframe so my CSS styles wont work.

Also playing around with jquery is useless, of course.

I know, iframes are not meant to manipulated but maybe its possible for blogger, somehow... in a distant world.

Is there a way or just not possible as i think?

Comment: Blogger comments can be easily styled. I am not sure what meant by iFrame. See this http://www.stylifyyourblog.com/2012/02/threaded-comment-styles.html

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried styling your comment iframe?
you cannot style content inside iframe, but you could style your iframe .

Below is an example, add this just before closing the <head> tag.

```
<style type='text/css'>
#comment-editor {
background: #F9F9F9 url(http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-Bdsls_ui_vY/UX-d4NVcHiI/AAAAAAAAB3M/IIzD9w00lDs/s1600/form-gradient.gif) repeat-x scroll -1px -2px;
border: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);
border-radius: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgb(204, 204, 204);
padding: 5px;
width: 560px;
height: 224px !important;
}
</style>
```

So it will look like this!

[Screenshot of the resulting comment form!](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-ezlQkSrrja4/UX-gj97x52I/AAAAAAAAB3s/DzcDGCCigHg/s1600/blogger+comment.PNG)

Answer (score 0):

I never had a need to style comment section in Blogger, so I cannot help you in that regard.

But you could try to replace it with third-party comment systems like [IntenseDebate](http://www.intensedebate.com/).

It supports custom CSS and URL to external stylesheet and has lots of other useful features too.

If you decide to try it just remember to backup a template before making a switch in case you want to revert back.

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, please take a moment to accept the answer by clicking on a checkbox on the left of this answer.